# How to get Layer 3 Messages from GSM Modem

Tags: gsm, modem

I want to read `L3` or `Layer 3 Messages` from `GSM Modem`. Any kind of modem that can help me to get and read `L3` messages. And how can I get them?

So I want your advice to chose a modem that make me read `L3` messages, and how can I get them.

Thanks and Best Regards.

Comment: You can get selected bits of information via AT commands, but for the full L3 air interface info, you need one of the chipset manufacturer's logging tools.  They're not normally available in the public domain.

Comment: Could u provide me with information about these chipset manufacturer's logging tools?

Comment: Ask the chipset manufacturer.  But usually they don't give them out, unless you have a non-disclosure agreement, e.g. customers or test equipment suppliers.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you will be able to poke around with low level network messages from any chip manufacturer.

When I worked in Ericsson and later ST-Ericsson, we developed a base mobile platform that we sold to our customers (Sony Ericsson, LG, Sharp and others). Agreement with each customer was varying, but they typically were given a copy of some parts of our source code. But none of them were ever given any code related to the network signalling part of our platform.